# Can regular instances of a class call constant functions?

Tags: c++, class, constants, member

I know that constant objects or functions can only operate on constant members but does it work the other way around?

Comment: Why haven't you tried it? (The answer is "yes, the object gets passed as `const T* this` to the call)

Comment: The compiler can implicitly cast an object to a `const&` of that type.  So where a non const object seems to be used to call a const function, the implicit const cast of that object is actually being used.  (Just as if you passed a non const object to any function that explicitly takes a `const&`)

Comment: @MatsPetersson Because in C++, something compiling and executing successfully is not proof enough that it is valid and not e.g. undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Regular (non const) class member functions can call any const and non const class member functions.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is **Yes**.

That is the beauty of `const` functions in C++. You can overload a method based on its `const`-ness:

```
class Vector
{
public:
   int GetItem();
   int GetItem() const;
};
```

A `const Vector` object would cause call to const method, but a non-const (`Vector`) would cause call to non-const. Let the compiler figure out which method (const or non-const) to call. Hence:

```
v.GetItem();
```

May call any of them, depending on actual type of `v`.

Why does C++ allows it considering the case where any "*Get*" method should be a read-only function? 
Well, not a language-lawyer justification, consider this.

vector v;
v[0] = 10;

If the overloaded operator in `vector<>` is declared as `const`, it won't allow the operator (`[]`) to be used on left side (i.e. as an l-value). 
*If* only non-const is provided, this will fail:

```
void process(const vector<int>& v)
{
    cout << v[0]; // Must call const op []
}
```

But since method can be overload on the basis of `const`, compiler figures out which overload to call.

On the other hand, C++ allows `const` to cast to non-const, and vice versa (`const_cast` and C-style cast), you can always call the other version from a (non-)const object.

```
((Vector*)&cv)->GetItem();
```